# Cortana skill 'deploy to group' is not working for new user

Tags: cortana, cortana-skills-kit, cortana-invoke

A month ago when https://my.knowledge.store/ was not existing I was able to edit the Cortana channel on dev.botframework.com, add new users to 'deploy to group' option and share the link with those users. Once user log in to their MSA and accept the skill they would be able to use the skill.

Recently, due to site changes Microsoft came up with new site called https://my.knowledge.store/workspace where Cortana channel and its publishing will be managed. I completely followed following link to deploy to group 
https://help.knowledge.store/system_concepts/publishing/index.html#publish-to-group

but, I see few differences this time. It does not give 
1. Link to share 
2. Once deployed NEW users added are not tied to skill yet.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

'Publish to group' should be working. When you publish to group using the steps mentioned in the link, it will give you [group access URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoXr3.png). This is the link you need to share for new users to test and use that skill.

Comment: Yes, this is true as per the documentation. But, link is not generated for me. I tried all the browsers.

Comment: Can you see group access URL field or is that field missing? Can you share screen shot?

Comment: group access URL field is missing. I can't attach a scree shot here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate the link now. Please let us know if that is not hte case.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I'm able to see the links now.